# Allow USB device access from SSH session

Tags: linux, ssh, usb, remote

I am trying to set up a RaspberryPI 3 connected to a Canon EOS 350D (Rebel TX for American friends) for a timelapse using `gphoto2`.

Everything works perfectly locally (monitor and keyboard connected to the pi). I can run `gphoto2 --auto-detect`, `gphoto2 --capture-image` and all the commands work as they should.

If I log out with `exit` from the local user and connect through SSH **to the same user** from another computer it stops working and I get this error message:

```
0.216588 gp_libusb1_open [libusb1.c:389](0): 'libusb_open (port->pl->d, &port->pl->dh)' failed: Access denied (insufficient permissions) (-3)
```

which probably means I don't have write access to the device but I am not completely sure.

If from remote I use root through `sudo` then it works again probably because root has all the permissions, but I need to make it work from remote without root.

If then I log back in from local it starts working again as it should even from remote.

Since the problem is with remote access to a usb device then I guess the problem is related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46332/why-can-i-not-see-my-usb-connected-android-device-over-ssh), but that solution is for disks and not serial devices.

After extensive googling I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem (working from local, not from remote), let alone a solution.

What I think I need is a way to tell the system to grant write access to the `pi` user even if it logs from SSH.

Comment: Serial device? The usage of libusb and gphoto2 (a PTP/MTP client) doesn't sound anything like serial.

Comment: I wanted to make clear in the title that it's not mass storage, I don't know the correct wording. How would I word it differently?
I am not trying to just access pictures from the memory, but to actively shoot and control the camera

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44308 - I expect that the issue is with libusb and permissions, so the udev fixed here will probably work, or at least take you quite far towards your goal.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT It's not a drive at all, it's a camera that has to take photos upon command from the computer.

Comment: @davidgoThanks a lot, that with a bit of refining worked like a charm. Feel free to post the answer so I can select as correct. Even though it still feels like a workaround. i.e. I am loosening protection while imho I should be able to gain the same access level from ssh as from local.

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni I see, I kinda thought it was either some pre-USB camera (the kind that _actually_ used a rs232 serial port), or one using a very proprietary interface.